# javascript - Create multidimensional array from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I would like to create in JavaScript multidimensional array like this:

```
var multiLayer = [
  ["First", "Second", 4],
  [5, 6, 3],
  [3, 2, 1]
];
```

From simple array like that

```
var simple = [
  "First",
  "Second",
  4,
  5,
  6,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  1
];
```

Here is my code yet

```
var multi = [];
var howMuchBreak = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < simple.length; i++) {
  multi.push(simple[i + howMuchBreak])
}
```

Variable howMuchBreak defines on which position in the index must be create next nested array.

Comment: You can use the [Lodash chunk function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk). also available as it's own [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.chunk)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.slice(start, end)` and increment the start by the desired sub-array length:

```js
var simple = [
  "First",
  "Second",
  4,
  5,
  6,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  1
];
var multiLayer = [];
// sub array length, in your example 3
var l = 3;
for (var i=0; i<simple.length; i += l) {
  multiLayer.push(simple.slice(i, i+l));
}
console.log(multiLayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using the remainder `%` operator. The other answer solves the problem in fewer lines (actually, the other answer does it in 18 i do it in 19) but i am adding this just to acquaint you with the `%` operator, very useful.

Quoting from MDN:

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.

Ponder the code and try to find out why and how this operator fits your situation :)

```js
var simple = [
  "First",
  "Second",
  4,
  5,
  6,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  1
];

var multi = [];
var sub_array_length = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < simple.length; i++) {
if(i % sub_array_length === 0) { 
multi[multi.length] = [];
} 
multi[multi.length - 1].push(simple[i]);
}

console.log(multi);
```

Answer (score 1):

or using while...

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var array = [], chunk = 3;

while (arr.length > 0){ array.push(arr.splice(0, chunk)); }

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Your answer is the shortest in terms of line-length (even after you multi-linify the array) :)

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't preserve the original (one-dimensional) array.

Comment: @insert_name_here I would say that is negligible since it will provide the correct results when supplied with the original array.

Comment: However, I believe there is a small misunderstanding, the entire solution relies on the use of `splice` which isn't really what OP asked for (since it modifies the original array).

Comment: However, I believe there is a small misunderstanding, the entire solution relies on the use of `splice` which isn't really what OP asked for (since it modifies the original array).

Comment: did they, where? :/

Answer (score 0):

**I made three variations:**

## First - Adaptive limiter

What it does is, well, do what you want but adapt if there's space left.

Example:

- Array: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- Break by: `2`
- Will generate: `[ [1,2], [3,4], [5] ]`

  var simple = [
        "First",
        "Second",
        4,
        5,
        6,
        3,
        3,
        2,
        1
      ];

  ```
  var multi = [];
  var howMuchBreak = 2;
  var i = 0; // start counting simple array elements
  var x = 0; // start counting limited array elements

  while (i < simple.length) {

    var limitedArray = [];
    x = 0;
    while (x < howMuchBreak && i < simple.length) {
      limitedArray.push(simple[i]);
      x++;
      i++;
    }

    multi.push(limitedArray);

  }
  ```

## Second - Non-adaptive limiter

Also does what you want but it doesn't adapt to extra space.

Example:

- Array: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- Break by: `2`
- Will generate: `[ [1,2], [3,4], [5, undefined] ]`

  var simple = [
        "First",
        "Second",
        4,
        5,
        6,
        3,
        3,
        2,
        1
      ];

  ```
  var multi = [];
  var howMuchBreak = 2;
  var i = 0; // start counting simple array elements
  var x = 0; // start counting limited array elements

  while (i < simple.length) {

    var limitedArray = [];
    x = 0;
    while (x < howMuchBreak) {
      limitedArray.push(simple[i]);
      x++;
      i++;
    }

    multi.push(limitedArray);

  }
  ```

## Third - ES6 API-like

It does the same as the others above but with more elegance. Also, I wanted to introduce you to new features of javascript to improve your code.

That code uses a config JSON with two properties:

- adaptive: `<boolean>` (defaults to true)
- breakBy: `<integer>`

Simply pass the simple array first and then the config to the simpleToMulti function:

`let multi = simpleToMulti( simpleArray, config );`

Example 1:

- Array: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- config: `{ adaptive: true, breakBy: 3 }`
- Will generate: `[ [1,2,3], [4,5] ]`

Example 2:

- Array: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- config: `{ adaptive: false, breakBy: 2 }`
- Will generate: `[ [1,2], [3,4], [5, undefined] ]`

  ```
  let simple = ["First", "Second", 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 1];

  let config = {
    breakBy: 4,
    adaptive: true
  };

  function simpleToMulti(arr, config) {

    // normalize config
    if (config.breakBy === undefined) {
      console.warn('simpleToMulti: You must inform the breakBy config property');
      return;
    }
    config.adaptive = config.adaptive === undefined ? true : config.adaptive;

    // do the magic
    let limitedArray = [];
    let multiArray = [];
    arr.forEach( value => {

      if (limitedArray.length < config.breakBy) {
        limitedArray.push(value);
      }

      if (limitedArray.length === config.breakBy) {
        multiArray.push(limitedArray);
        limitedArray = [];
      }

    });

    if (limitedArray.length !== 0) {
      if (config.adaptive) {
        multiArray.push(limitedArray);
      } else {
        while (limitedArray.length < config.breakBy) {
          limitedArray.push(undefined);
        }
        multiArray.push(limitedArray);
      }
    }

    return multiArray;
  }


  let multi = simpleToMulti(simple, config);
  console.log(multi);
  ```

Comment: The non-adaptive version is not a feature, it is a bug (why would you want that behavior ?). Also, there is no need to use `let` if you aren't utilizing block-scoping; you should just stick with `var` for these cases (where the `let` will be bound to the `global` scope or the enclosing function`s scope).

Comment: Here is your example but with some modifications i made (if you are interested): https://jsfiddle.net/syxxuw13/

Comment: Thanks! I got used to always using `let` and forgot that `var` also does the same if I'm already inside a function. Not exactly the same... but still ok for that case.

I wouldn't say that the non-adaptive is a bug because maybe he really wants every array to have the same length, idk, it wasn't clear so I did it just to be sure. 

Thanks for taking the time to make the modifications! (:

Answer (score 0):

I've been spending the last hour trying to find a way to create a multidimensional array from an array of ints. This is what I finally came up with (`reduceRight`and `times`are from the [lodash library](https://lodash.com)).

```
let dimensions = [1, 2, 3]

_.reduceRight(dimensions, (result, dimension) => {
    return _.times(dimension, () => result)    
}, [])
```